# Get a certain character after a regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a JavaScript application and I need a regex for the following thing:

I have different strings that look like:

```
"./resources/red_B.png" or "./resources/red_1.png"
```

I want to get the character after the `red_` text, so I want a Regex that returns the character `B` or `1`.

I am not a Regex star so I was wondering if someone knows the solution to the problem.

Comment: What is your regex thus far? Post that. Show us where it's failing. Have you used sites like https://regexr.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `\/resources\/red_\K(\w)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h8bXE3/2)

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you want:

```
red_(\w)+\.
```

catch it with groups in js as said in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

You could match `./resources/red_` followed by capturing in a group not a dot using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `([^.]+)`

[`\.\/resources\/red_([^.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/en6BQB/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "./resources/red_B.png",
  "./resources/red_1.png"
];
let pattern = /\.\/resources\/red_([^\.]+)/;
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.match(pattern)[1]);
});
```